# Angular UI-Bootstrap Carousel com Multiplos slides

Tags: angularjs, carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

Estou usando o Carousel [UI-Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) com AngularJs,  porem só mostra 1 slide por vez. Queria multiplos slides igual a esses exemplos abaixo.

[Bootstrap 3 Multiple Slide Carousel](https://www.bootply.com/123662), outro exemplo,
[Bootstrap 3 Carousel Multiple Items Increment by 1](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLQvoz)

É possivel fazer Multiplos Slides usando Ui-Bootstrap com AngularJs? Ou teria que usar a diretiva [Angular Slick](http://vasyabigi.github.io/angular-slick/)?

[Meu exemplo usando Ui-Bootstrap](https://codepen.io/braian-silva/pen/GBaZOQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Optei por usar Owl Carousel no AngularJs.](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2)

app.owl.js

```
angular
.module('appCliente.owl', []);

    function owlCarousel() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: false,
            link: link
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope) {
            scope.initCarousel = function (element) {

                console.log('initcarousel');
                var defaultOptions = {};

                var customOptions = scope.$eval($(element).attr('data-options'));
                // combine the two options objects
                for (var key in customOptions) {
                    defaultOptions[key] = customOptions[key];
                }
                // Inicia o OwlCarousel
                var curOwl = $(element).data('owlCarousel');

                if (!angular.isDefined(curOwl)) {
                    $(element).owlCarousel(defaultOptions);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    angular
        .module('appCliente.owl')
        .directive('owlCarousel', owlCarousel);
```

owlCarousel-directive.js

```
angular
    .module('appCliente.owl')
    .directive('owlCarouselItem', owlCarouselItem);

function owlCarouselItem() {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: false
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element) {
        /* Ultimo item do ng-repeat */
        if (scope.$last) {
            console.log('1st element');
            scope.initCarousel(element.parent());
        }
    }
}
```

Index.html

```
<!-- OWL Carousel -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
            <h3 class="text-center alert novo">Novos Mangas</h3>
            <data-owl-carousel class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="owl-example" data-options="vm.default">
                <div owl-carousel-item="" class="thumb" ng-repeat="manga in vm.novosMangas">
                    <a ui-sref="nav.manga.detalhe({mangasId:manga.id})">
                        <img class="img2" data-ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{manga.capa}}" ng-if="manga.capa">
                        <img class="img2" src="/app/img/image.JPG" ng-if="!manga.capa">
                    </a>
                    <div class="centered">
                        {{manga.nome}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </data-owl-carousel>
        </div>
```